# How can I pass variables into my title with Latex Interpretation?

Tags: matlab

I would like some parameter values to appear where the white box is in my picture (`subplot(3,2,1)`).  It would be ideal if the interpretation in `title()` could be latex, like the others.

I have tried the following:

```
title( sprintf( ' $\delta$ = %s  $\rho$ = %s  $\xi$ = %s  m =  %s', delta, rho, xi, m), 'Interpreter', 'latex')
```

But I get the following error:

```
Warning: Control Character '\d' is not valid. See 'doc sprintf' for control characters valid in the format string. 
> In SIXY_sol (line 21) 
Warning: Error updating Text.

 String must have valid interpreter syntax:
 $
```

How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a problem with using the LaTeX interpreter but rather with the way you have used `sprintf`. In the [docs for `sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html),  scroll down to the section *Text Before or After Formatting Operators*. Here you will see that the `\` character is used to begin an escape sequence so that you can do things like `\n` for a new line. You actually want `\` to appear in your string so you need to escape the escape character. From that table in the docs you need to replace all of your `\` with `\\`.

Try:

```
title( sprintf( ' $\\delta$ = %s  $\\rho$ = %s  $\\xi$ = %s  m =  %s', delta, rho, xi, m), 'Interpreter', 'latex')
```